# what is the difference between weights="cell" and weights="proportional" in r package emmeans

Tags: r, emmeans

I want to calculate the marginal means in a `glm` model with discrete  predictors and unbalanced data. Using function `emmeans` of `emmeans` package to get the marginal means gives me different results for setting `weights="cell"` and `weights="proportional"`. The package documentation says `"proportional"` uses weight in proportion to the frequencies (in the original data) of the factor combinations that are averaged over and `"cells"` uses weight according to the frequencies of the cells being averaged. But I do not understand what it really means?! Please see a simplified version of my r code below!
I would be appriciated for any help.

```
model <- glm(formula=y~x1+x2, data=df, family=gaussian)
library(emmeans)
marginal_means_cells <- summary(emmeans(model, "x1", weights="cells"))
marginal_means_prop  <- summary(emmeans(model, "x1", weights="prop"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is further discussed in the ["messy data" vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/messy-data.html#weights) in the **emmeans** package. Suppose in a 2-factor design, you have cell frequencies like this:

```
             Treatment
   Dose  |  A    B    C   |  sum
   ------------------------------
     a   |  5    0    3   |    8
     b   | 11    3    9   |   23
   ------------------------------
    sum  | 16    3   12   |   31
```

Then using "prop" weights, the marginal means for Treatment will all be computed with weights 8 and 23, and the marginal means for Dose will all be computed with weights 16, 3, and 12.

Using "cells" weights, the marginal mean for Treatment are computed with weights 5 and 11 for A, 0 and 3 for B, and 3 and 9 for C; and the marginal means for Dose are computed with weights 5, 0, 3 for a, and 11, 3, 9 for b.

Ifthe model contains the `Treatment:Dose` interaction, the cell with 0 observations cannot even be estimated, and hence using "prop" weights, neither can the marginal means for Treatment B or Dose a. But those marginal means can be estimated with "cells" weights.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do not have any interaction in the model but many cells with 0 frequency. I think the best way to estimate the marginal means would be "prop" weights, right?

Comment: It's hard to say what's best in your situation. Maybe you need to talk to a consultant. The default is equal weights, which I think you should consider.